# how to run a function called in a thread outside that thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to know the possibility to run a function in main thread, where the calling function is in another thread.

Consider below example

```
from thread import start_new_thread

def add(num1,num2):

    res = num1 + num2
    display(res)

def display(ans):
    print ans

thrd = start_new_thread(add,(2,5))
```

here i am calling `add()` in a new thread. which in turns calls `display()` i.e., display is also running in same thread.

I want to know how to run `display()` outside that thread.

**New code as per the answers below**

If i am trying to accept input from user and print the result. Its asking for input only once but not repeatedly...

from threading import Thread  # threading is better than the thread module
from Queue import Queue

q = Queue()  # use a queue to pass messages from the worker thread to the main thread

```
def add():
    num1=int(raw_input('Enter 1st num : '))
    num2=int(raw_input('Enter 2nd num : '))
    res = num1 + num2
    # send the function 'display', a tuple of arguments (res,)
    # and an empty dict of keyword arguments
    q.put((display, (res,), {}))

def display(ans):
    print ('Sum of both two num is : %d ' % ans)

thrd = Thread(target=add)
thrd.start()

while True:  # a lightweight "event loop"
#    ans = q.get()
#    display(ans)
#    q.task_done()
    f, args, kwargs = q.get()
    f(*args, **kwargs)
    q.task_done()
```

and when i run the code, the result is as below

**Current Result**

```
Enter 1st num : 5
Enter 2nd num : 6
Sum of both two num is : 11
```

**Required Result**

```
Enter 1st num : 5
Enter 2nd num : 6
Sum of both two num is : 11 

Enter 1st num : 8
Enter 2nd num : 2
Sum of both two num is : 10

Enter 1st num : 15
Enter 2nd num : 3
Sum of both two num is : 18
```

where i need it to be asking for inputs after printing result every time, like below

Comment: Create a new thread and run the function there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if i create a new thread and running the function will again run is another thread. but i don't want to run it in a thread at all. it should sun normally.

Comment: All code runs in a thread. Without a thread, nothing can run. You need to be clearer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan u r right, i mean to say i need `display()` to run in main thread

Comment: Please edit the question to say so

Comment: @DavidHeffernan edited as suggested...

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you want all calls to `display` to happen on the main thread. Something like this unsophisticated example, using a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to send messages to the main thread, should work:

```
from threading import Thread  # threading is better than the thread module
from Queue import Queue

q = Queue()  # use a queue to pass messages from the worker thread to the main thread

def add(num1,num2):
    res = num1 + num2
    q.put(res)  # send the answer to the main thread's queue

def display(ans):
    print ans

thrd = Thread(target=add, args=(2,5))
thrd.start()

while True:  # a lightweight "event loop"
    ans = q.get()
    display(ans)
    q.task_done()
```

---

A typical generalisation of this lightweight "messaging framework" is to program your worker threads to put arbitrary functions and arguments on `q`. This allows you to make the main thread dumber. The code that deals with q would then look like this:

```
def add(num1,num2):
    res = num1 + num2
    # send the function 'display', a tuple of arguments (res,)
    # and an empty dict of keyword arguments
    q.put((display, (res,), {}))

# snip

while True:
    # now the main thread doesn't care what function it's executing.
    # previously it assumed it was sending the message to display().
    f, args, kwargs = q.get()
    f(*args, **kwargs)
    q.task_done()
```

---

From here you can see how you can design a robust and decoupled multi-threaded application. You equip every worker thread object with an input `Queue`, and a global [mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) thread is responsible for shuffling messages between threads.

Note the the `Queue`-based approach to multithreading assumes that none of the threads share any global objects. If they do, you'd also need to ensure all shared objects have associated locks (see [the `threading` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects)). Of course, this is then prone to the difficult synchronisation errors that the `Queue`-based approach seeks to avoid. The moral of the story, even though it seems like hard work, is to keep shared state to a minimum.

Comment: i am getting error `f, args, kwargs = q.get()
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in my code. The worker thread should be putting a _tuple_ on the queue: `q.put((display, (res,), {}))` (note the extra pair of parentheses). I've fixed it in the code snippet.

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao If my answer solved your problem, would you consider marking it as accepted?

Comment: as it was weekend, i did not check. Once i go to my workplace i will try and do.

Comment: with the example its working, but actually i need add method to take input and process. It should be in continues process in the thread. I have appended in my question the requirement.

Comment: I've read the addendum to your question. Why are you trying to use threads at all?

Comment: i have an application in which i incorporated a messaging system. In that the i used Socket. the listening state of the messaging service will be running in a thread. which calls a procedure from  another class which will display a message in a window. so when there is call to that class, my app is just hanging as it is beeing called from a thread. So thought of running that calling bit in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to impement [rendezvous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_%28Plan_9%29) or a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29)